# Why can't I access a specific variable inside of a threaded class

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, flask

I'm new to Python so this could be a simple fix.

I am using Flask and sockets for this Python project. I am starting the socket on another thread so I can actively listen for new messages. I have an array variable called 'SocketConnections' that is within my UdpComms class. The variable gets a new 'Connection' appended to it when a new socket connection is made. That works correctly. My issue is that when I try to read 'SocketConnections' from outside of the thread looking in, it is an empty array.

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import UdpComms as U
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/talk', methods=['POST'])
def talk():
    global global_server_socket
    apples = global_server_socket.SocketConnections

    return jsonify(message=apples)
    
global_server_socket = None

def start_server():
    global global_server_socket
    sock = U.UdpComms(udpIP="127.0.0.1", portTX=8000, portRX=8001, enableRX=True, suppressWarnings=True)
    i = 0
    global_server_socket = sock
    while True:
        i += 1

        data = sock.ReadReceivedData() # read data

        if data != None: # if NEW data has been received since last ReadReceivedData function call
            print(data) # print new received data

        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
    server_thread.start()
    app.run(debug=True,host='192.168.0.25')
```

**UdpComms.py**

```
import json
import uuid 

class UdpComms():
    def __init__(self,udpIP,portTX,portRX,enableRX=False,suppressWarnings=True):
        self.SocketConnections = []
        import socket

        self.udpIP = udpIP
        self.udpSendPort = portTX
        self.udpRcvPort = portRX
        self.enableRX = enableRX
        self.suppressWarnings = suppressWarnings # when true warnings are suppressed
        self.isDataReceived = False
        self.dataRX = None

        # Connect via UDP
        self.udpSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # internet protocol, udp (DGRAM) socket
        self.udpSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # allows the address/port to be reused immediately instead of it being stuck in the TIME_WAIT state waiting for late packets to arrive.
        self.udpSock.bind((udpIP, portRX))

        # Create Receiving thread if required
        if enableRX:
            import threading
            self.rxThread = threading.Thread(target=self.ReadUdpThreadFunc, daemon=True)
            self.rxThread.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.CloseSocket()

    def CloseSocket(self):
        # Function to close socket
        self.udpSock.close()

    def SendData(self, strToSend):
        # Use this function to send string to C#
        self.udpSock.sendto(bytes(strToSend,'utf-8'), (self.udpIP, self.udpSendPort))

    def SendDataAddress(self, strToSend, guid):
        # Use this function to send string to C#
        print('finding connection: ' + guid)

        if self.SocketConnections:
            connection = self.GetConnectionByGUID(guid)
            print('found connection: ' + guid)
            if connection is not None:
                self.udpSock.sendto(bytes(strToSend,'utf-8'), connection.Address)

    def ReceiveData(self):
        if not self.enableRX: # if RX is not enabled, raise error
            raise ValueError("Attempting to receive data without enabling this setting. Ensure this is enabled from the constructor")

        data = None
        try:
            data, _ = self.udpSock.recvfrom(1024)
            print('Socket data recieved from: ', _)
            if self.IsNewConnection(_) == True:
                print('New socket')
                self.SendDataAddress("INIT:" + self.SocketConnections[-1].GUID, self.SocketConnections[-1].GUID)
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
        except WindowsError as e:
            if e.winerror == 10054: # An error occurs if you try to receive before connecting to other application
                if not self.suppressWarnings:
                    print("Are You connected to the other application? Connect to it!")
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unexpected Error. Are you sure that the received data can be converted to a string")

        return data

    def ReadUdpThreadFunc(self): # Should be called from thread
        self.isDataReceived = False # Initially nothing received

        while True:
            data = self.ReceiveData()  # Blocks (in thread) until data is returned (OR MAYBE UNTIL SOME TIMEOUT AS WELL)
            self.dataRX = data # Populate AFTER new data is received
            self.isDataReceived = True
            # When it reaches here, data received is available

    def ReadReceivedData(self):
        data = None

        if self.isDataReceived: # if data has been received
            self.isDataReceived = False
            data = self.dataRX
            self.dataRX = None # Empty receive buffer

            if data != None and data.startswith('DIALOG:'): #send it info
                split = data.split(':')[1]

        return data
    
    class Connection:
        def __init__(self, gUID, address) -> None:
            self.GUID = gUID
            self.Address = address

    def IsNewConnection(self, address):
        for connection in self.SocketConnections:
            if connection.Address == address:
                return False
    
        print('Appending new connection...')
        connection = self.Connection(str(uuid.uuid4()),address)
        self.SocketConnections.append(connection)

        return True

    def GetConnectionByGUID(self, guid):
        for connection in self.SocketConnections:
            if connection.GUID == guid:
                return connection
        return None
```

As mentioned above. When IsNewConnection() is called in UdpComms it does append a new object to SocketConnections. It's just trying to view the SocketConnections in the app.route that is empty. My plans are to be able to send socket messages from the app.routes

Comment: A production Flask server can be spread across multiple processes, in which case the global variables are not shared.  You realize that UDP doesn't really have the concept of a "connection", right?

Comment: @TimRoberts I am aware that UDP doesn't truly have connections. But I can save the address of the ones who connect and send stuff back to the address. Is there something in Flask where I can get global variables? Or maybe another web library that isn't Flask?

Comment: You may end up having to use some kind of database, or some simple long-running server process.  The flaw in trying to do connections with UDP is that you cannot know when the other end stops listening.  Unlike TCP, UDP is quite happy to let you send datagrams into empty space, even if no one is listening.  How will you clear your connection pool?

Answer (score 2):

For interprocess communication you may try to use something like shared memory documented [here](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Instead of declaring your `self.SocketConnections` as a list `= []`
you'd use `self.SocketConnections = Array('i', range(10))` (you are then limited to remembering only 10 connections though).